# ASP.NET TextBox ignores update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a GridView with a item template defined like:

```
public class ToolLogTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public String DataField { get; set; }

    public ToolLogTemplate(String column)
    {
        DataField = column;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        var textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Predictable;
        textBox.CssClass = "ToolLog";
        textBox.AutoPostBack = true;
        textBox.DataBinding += textBox_DataBinding;

        container.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }

    void textBox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var context = DataBinder.GetDataItem(textBox.NamingContainer);
        textBox.Text = DataBinder.Eval(context, DataField).ToString();
    }
}
```

The GridView is inside of a UpdatePanel defined like:

```
        UpdatePanel updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
```

The TextChanged event of the TextBoxes in the GridView trigger a full refresh of the page. My understanding was that by wrapping the TextBoxes in a UpdatePanel it would trigger a partial refresh instead. Am I misunderstanding this?

Update in response to the newest comment on the question:

I have some javascript attached to the textboxes:

```
                currentTextBox.Attributes.Add("onFocus", String.Format("document.getElementById('RowTextBox').value = {0}; document.getElementById('ColTextBox').value = {1}; this.style.backgroundColor='#ffeb9c';", i, j));
                currentTextBox.Attributes.Add("onBlur", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffff'");
```

It just sets the colors of the textbox and saves where it is in the gridview. The updatepanel works as expected with the menu and button I have in it, it's just the textboxes that cause a full postback.

Comment: No, you're not misunderstanding that it would trigger only a partial postback...  But the entire page lifecycle still applies.  What behavior is not working as you'd expect?

Comment: And is there any reason it's not just declared in the markup instead of in code?

Comment: Everything is added from database tables, So I do it in the code behind.

Comment: As to the behavior I expect, it would be just the update panel contents refreshing, not the whole page.

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue in a clean test environment and found that it works as expected: the textboxes post back without causing the rest of the page (i.e., everything outside of the UpdatePanel) to reload. Have you somehow set your ScriptManager to EnablePartialRendering = false? Are you using multiple methods of Ajax on your page (sometimes they conflict and cause a full postback)? We might need some more information about your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well unfortunately I was never able to make the model described here work. Instead I put an invisible button inside of the updatepanel and had javascript click it on the textboxes onchange event. I don't know why this method works and the TextChanged one doesn't, but that's how it ended up going down.

Answer (score 0):

*Upon seeing update code, I have revised my answer...*

The UpdatePanel needs to be told which controls it should respond to.  You can do this by adding Triggers.  In your case, you have TextBox controls within a GridView.  These Textboxes are set to autopostback.  Since they are within the GridView, I believe the GridView is treating them like a RowCommand.  Using your original code, I would recommend you add the following:

```
UpdatePanel updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

gridView.OnRowCommand = "GridViewRowCommand";

AsyncPostbackTrigger newTrigger = new AsyncPostbackTrigger();
newTrigger.ControlID = gridView.ControlID;
updatePanel.Triggers.Add(newTrigger);
```

Within your codebehind, you would need to do something like this:

```
protected void GridViewRowCommand(object sender, RowCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var myTextBox = e.Row.FindControl("myTextBoxID");
    // Do some work
}
```

Comment: I have edited my original question in response to your answer.

Comment: Bummer.  Like @samiz mentioned, do you have a ScriptManager setup on the page?

Comment: In the master page (which this page derives from) I have a script manager like: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />

Comment: Now that I've re-read your update, I think I know where the problem is at.  Since those textboxes are within a GridView, its the GridView.RowCommand event that you need to bind as a trigger.  Then, within the RowCommandEvent, you will need to "FindControl" the textbox in that row and make it behave accordingly.

Comment: I would suggest deleting those updated code sections in your question.

Comment: Tried to do it like your response, still the same behavior. I don't use the insert/update/delete links.